# Access beginner queries

Tags: ms-access

my question involves access in which I am learning only the basic of basic so far. my question however is how combine fields into one. I am not sure as to how to explain it but ill try my best. this is currently what I have:

```
Name      quantity     cost
name1         5        $20.00
name1        25         $6.00
name1         2        $50.00
name2        etc.       etc.
name2        etc.       etc.
```

now what I want to do is combine all those name1's ( as well as name2's but separated) into one which will also combine the quantities as well as the cost fields so that it looks this:

```
Name      quantity     cost
name1         32        $76.00
name2      whatever #    whatever $
```

the problem however is that I am stumped on how to achieve this. I would appreciate the help you all can give me.

Comment: Hint:  You want an aggregation query that uses `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a TOTALS Query. It should be something along the lines of,

```
SELECT 
    nameFieldName, 
    Sum(quantityFieldName) As TotalQty, 
    Sum(costFieldName) As TotalCost
FROM
    yourTableName
GROUP BY
    nameFieldName;
```

For more info on TOTALS Query : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169472%28v=nav.70%29.aspx